# kubernetes with slurm, is this correct setup?

Tags: kubernetes, containers, hpc, slurm

i saw that some people use Kubernetes co-exist with slurm, I was just curious as to why you need kubernetes with slurm? what is the main difference between kubernetes and slurm?

Answer (score 14):

[Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/overview.html) is open source job scheduling system for large and small Linux clusters. It is mainly used as Workload Manager/Job scheduler. Mostly used in HPC (High Performance Computing) and sometimes in BigData.

[Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) is an orchestration system for Docker containers using the concepts of ”labels” and ”pods” to group containers into logical units. It was mainly created to run micro-services and AFAIK currently `Kubernetes` is not supporting Slurm.

Slumr as Job scheduler have more scheduling options than Kubernetes, but K8s is container orchestration system not only Job scheduler. For example `Kubernetes` is supporting Array jobs and `Slurm` supports Parallel and array jobs. If you want to dive in to scheduling check [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.03102.pdf) article.

As I mentioned before, Kubernetes is more focused on container orchestration and Slumr is focused on Job/Workload scheduling. 
Only thing comes to my mind is that someone needed very personal-customized cluster using [WLM-Operator](https://github.com/sylabs/wlm-operator) + K8s + Slurm + Singularity to execute HPC/BigData jobs.

Usually Slurm Workload Manager is used by many of the world's supercomputers to optimize locality of task assignments on parallel computers.